# how to get json array of Ext.tree.Panel on Extjs 4.0

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I encountered a problem when I was using extjs4.0.I download data with Ext.data.TreeStore,Downloading data is a JSON array,whitch showed up in a Tree.panle with checkbox.I modified the selection state of itme and submitted it,use follow code:

```
    var d=store.lastOptions.node.childNodes;
    var postData="";
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
    {
          postData+=JSON.stringify(d[i].data)+",";
    }
    postData="["+postData.substring(0,postData.length-1)+"]";
    $.ajax({
          url: '/test.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: postData,
     ...
```

But the checked in the JSON array"{children:[{checked:false,..}{checked:false,...}]}" is always false.I guess I didn't use the correct way to get the submitted JSON data,So there will be such a mistake.
thanks every one for help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    Ext.define('Test.Window', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

        closeAction: 'destroy',
        border: false,
        width: 560,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        closable: true,
        resizable: false,
        layout: 'fit',

        initComponent: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.callParent(arguments);

            me.button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Send',
                handler : function(btn) {
                    var me = btn.up('window');
                    var root = me.tree.getRootNode();

                    var a = Array();
                    for (var i=0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++) {
                        var data = root.childNodes[i].data;
                        a.push(
                            {
                            text: data.text,
                            checked: data.checked
                            // ... something more
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    var postData = Ext.JSON.encode({
                        children: a
                    });
                    alert(postData);
                }   
            });

            me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                        text: "detention",
                        checked: true,
                        leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                        text: "homework", 
                        checked: true,
                        leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                        text: "buy lottery tickets", 
                        checked: true,
                        leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });

            me.tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                useArrows: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                animate: true,
                enableDD: false,
                width: '100%',
                flex: 1,
                border: false,
                rootVisible: false,
                allowChildren: true,
                store: me.store,
                tbar: [
                    me.button
                ]
            });

            me.add(me.tree);
        }



    }); 


    var win = new Test.Window({

    });
    win.show();

});
```

Fiddle can be found [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kip).